# Advanced Types in Object in Object

Tags: typescript, angular8

I can't figure out how to use multiple advanced types in object.
I have an object Animal in a parent component and function to some condition, I have to display a child component relative to a specific type; but I have the error below and no idea for a solution.

```
interface Animal {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  type: Bird | Fish;
}

interface Bird {
  fly(): void;
}
 
interface Fish {
  swim(): void;
}
```

`Property 'swim' does not exist on type 'Bird | Fish'. Property 'swim' does not exist on type 'Bird'.`

I tried to find something in the [typescript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#unions-with-common-fields) but I didn't found any solution.

**Advanced exemple:**

interface.ts:

```
interface Animal {
  id: number;
  code: string;
  metadata: Bird | Fish;
}

interface basicForm {
  formLabel: string;
}

interface Bird extends basicForm {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  fly: string;
}
 
interface Fish extends basicForm {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  swim: string;
}
```

Parent component html:

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="formLabel">
  <app-fish-form *ngSwitchCase="'fishForm'" [detail]="detail"></app-fish-form>
  <app-bird-form *ngSwitchCase="'birdForm'" [detail]="detail"></app-bird-form>
</ng-container>
```

Parent component ts:

```
public detail: Animal;

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
  this._checkForm();
}

private _checkForm() {
  // res should be fishForm or birdForm
  *backendCall*then(res => this.detail.metadata.formLabel = res)
}
```

Child component (fish) html:

```
<input type="text" name="swim" [(ngModel)]="detail.swim" />
```

Child component (fish) ts:

```
@Input() detail: Animal;

ngOnInit() {
  this.detail.metadata.swim = 'yes';
}
```

In my opinion, it could be great if at the init of the child component I was able to cast the `this.detail.metadata as Fish;`

Comment: You say `Animal` is a "parent" but your implementation is very similar to a discriminated union. Yet even that would *work* - where is the error coming from? What are you actually trying to do - what's the end goal?

Comment: No, Animal is IN a parent component.
I'm in angular, I have a parent component which fetch and manipulate an object 'Animal', and fonction to the back I display a child component (thx to ngSwitch case) which stand for 'Bird' or 'Fish'.
And at the init of one of those child components, I have an error like `Property 'swim' does not exist on type 'Bird | Fish'. Property 'swim' does not exist on type 'Bird'.`

Comment: But *what is the code that causes that error*? You're asking us to solve a problem but you do not show us a [mcve] of the problem. Nor do you say what the solution is supposed to accomplish. I can *guess* you're doing `animal.type.swim()` but that doesn't help me tell you how to do it properly. Unless the only possible answer I can give you: "use a type guard" is satisfactory but I suspect it isn't.

Comment: @VLAZ I added a detailled exemple in the main question. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm missing why you are calling `swim()` or `fly()` directly on `type`. Inheritance is used to implement the same method in a different way according to its type.

*Below I will give you a solution that is similar to what you are doing, but it's meant to be a wrapper for your interfaces and not a parent class from which they should inherit*.

Inheritance is mainly meant to do something like this:

```
interface Animal {
  name: string;
  code: string;
  move: ()=> void;
}

class Fish implements Animal {
  name: string;
  code: string;
  constructor(name: string, code: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.code = code;
  }
  move() {
    console.log("I'm swimming...");
  }
}
 
class Bird implements Animal {
   name: string;
   code: string;
   constructor(name: string, code: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.code = code;
  }
  move() {
    console.log("I'm flying...");
  }
}
```

As you can see, both birds and fishes implement the same method `move()` but they act differently. This is the main purpose of inheritance and the "final" inheriting object is usually a class and not an interface.

On the other hand, if you just need a **wrapper** for a series of classes, instead of using inheritance, I suggest you this approach:

```
interface Bird {
  name: string
  age: number
  type: 'BIRD'
  fly: ()=>void
}
 
interface Fish {
  name: string
  age: number
  type: 'FISH'
  swim: ()=>void
}

type Animal = Fish | Bird;

let my_animal: Animal = {
  name: 'Karl'
  age: 8
  type: 'FISH' as 'FISH'
  swim: () => { console.log("I'm swimming...") }
}

if(my_animal.type === 'FISH'){
  my_animal.swim(); //Typescript will not complain here
}
```

Animal in this case act as a wrapper.